# Preserving `this` in the type returned by a generic constructor fn provided as argument to an activator function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a parent/child hierarchy.

`Parent` has a function called `child`, that accepts a ctor that allows Parent to be set generically. `child` then invokes the ctor, passing itself as the `Parent`.

I want the type of `Parent` to be preserved on the child type being created.

So for example...

```js
// A Parent / Child relationship:

class Child<P extends Parent> {
  constructor(readonly parent: P) {}
}

class Parent {

  child<T>(ctor: new <P extends Parent> (parent: P) => T) {
    return new ctor(this)
  }
}

// And trying to utilise the Parent / Child relationship:

class MyChild<P extends Parent> extends Child<P> { }

class MyParent extends Parent {
  foo = this.child(MyChild) // But 'foo' is MyChild<Parent> instead of MyChild<this>
}
```

I'm trying to get `foo` to be typed as `MyChild<this>`... but can only get `MyChild<Parent>` or `Child<this>`.

Is there a trick to getting `child` to return the type inferred from the constructor, and also set the containing class as its parent, WITHOUT having to explicitly provide `this` as the type argument for the parent?

In other words, `foo = this.child('foo', MyChild)` should set `foo` as `MyChild<this>`.

Here's a [link to the code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCAWBLEATAPABWgUwB4BdsA7FGDMAJ2PwD5oBvAKGmmAHsiJ8KBXYfNhQAUVMCg4gAntAAOlagC5oGAJQMAvo02NQkMvKL4GjZqySo0AFRpD+gpUWwB3aJhwFipZQdrQhcqkMlVWgAXjpLNSYWFip8HgoiaEcXO2F8JAgVU01tXShoAFlJBGR0LDxCEn1A30rPGFKLDDp6aDzwAuLyWvcqrx7qYxYAMzY2MOgMxAgAOmBzFCFippRs9SA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/W4a4Xw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I guess the idea was to create a DRY API that hides the wiring of 'this' as a parent. 

If we were to explicitly define the type like that then it defeats the purpose of trying to infer the return type from the constructor passed. It'd be far clearer to write `foo = new MyChild(this)`, but then we don't get the opportunity to tweak the constructed type.

Comment: Where do you want to avoid such "wiring"?  If it's in the definition of `child()`, then you need that, because `new <P extends Parent> (parent: P) => T` doesn't help you. If it's in the `foo =` line, then the only reason I had to do that is because [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQjAJN) is illegally circular. My fix gives you "proper typings", I think. So should I write an answer suggesting this, or do you want to [edit] the question to say that you will not accept an answer unless it is DRY in a particular way you will specify?

Comment: The circular reference actually demonstrates the problem more specifically, I suspect. Having a circular reference isn't illegal, per se, but trying to create the reference via `child()` seems to be a problem.  [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/Nlo0Ow) demonstrating how I'd like to use the `child()` fn to 'wire up' new children. Also showing how the circular reference is legal if foo is set to `new MyChild(this)`.

Comment: All usage of `this` is circular, but that's how classes work and idiomatic uses of it are generally supported. Circularity errors can be worked around in a number of ways, and explicitly writing out the type is the most direct and straightforward. If you don't like it, that's fine, but we're straying from the original topic; the answer to the question as asked is like "use `child<T>(c: new (p: this) => T) `" and any issues with circularity or DRYness would be followup questions. Do you agree and I'll write an answer? Or disagree and want to [edit] the question to reflect some other issue?

Comment: Understood... I updated the question, hopefully that is more specific. Do you think the title of the question should also be changed?

Comment: The title is probably fine.  Note that I don't have an answer to your new version of the question (although it's probably some flavor of "no this isn't possible") so I'm going to disengage.

Comment: I thought maybe a higher kinded type would help here, but I think it would require one per implementation of MyChild, which isn't convenient.